# How to present a view controller while performing background tasks?

Tags: multithreading, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com and swift

I have an initial view controller that presents the parse.com login.

Once the login is complete and the objects are saved in the background I want to present my navigation controller's root view controller (first controller linked in the storyboard).

How is this done with all the asynchronous calls?

This is what I have but it jumps back to the login screen and doesn't

```
func signUpViewController(signUpController: PFSignUpViewController!, didSignUpUser user: PFUser!) {
 currentUser = user as? User
 currentUser!.isManager = false
 var query = PFUser.query()
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if objects.count == 1 {
   currentUser!.isManager = true
  }
  currentUser?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
   if success == false || error != nil {
    println(error)
   } else {
    currentCompany = Company()
    currentCompany!.companyName = "My Company"
    currentCompany!.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
     if success == false {
      println(error)
     }
    })
   }
  })
 }
 dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpFromInitialToMessages", sender: self)
  // let vc = MessagesViewController()
  // self.navigationController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

 })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to initiate a UI transition/update inside the completion handler, you should insert a dispatch back to the main queue *inside* the completion handler closure:

```
var query = PFUser.query()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    // do something

    // when done, do some UI update, e.g. perform segue to another scene

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: self)
    }
}
```

This is an example with a simple query, but the idea works with any asynchronously called completion handler closure: Just dispatch the UI update back to the main queue from within the closure.